# how to fetch two fields from a single repository in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

```
@Repository
interface SchemeMemberRepository:JpaRepository<Entity,Long> {

    fun findBySchemeMemberName(schemeMemberName:String) : Optional<Entity>
}
```

In the code, I have fetched by `schemeMemberName`. Can it be fetched by two fields? As shown below.

```
 @Repository

interface SchemeMemberRepository:JpaRepository<Entity,Long> {

    fun findBySchemeMemberName(schemeMemberName:String,Name:String) : Optional<Entity>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
fun findBySchemeMemberNameAndName(schemeMemberName: String, Name: String) : Optional<Entity>
```

JPA method name parsing's quite sophisticated, and can handle multiple fields, range checks, case-insensitive matching, substring matching, subproperties, and much more; see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html).

(You might also consider returning a nullable value instead of an Optional.  Kotlin will ensure you handle the null case properly, and can do so more concisely.)

Comment: @AnjalyAbraham: What happened when it ‘didn't work’?  Also, can you post your `Entity` class?

Comment: can u please define what u meant? I didn't understand your question